# WebRTC data channel stack on readyState "conecting"

Tags: javascript, html, p2p, webrtc, peer

I am trying to create a webRTC connection with a datachannel (only), but when I use the code provided bellow, and run `initCall()`, the readyState of the data channel is stack on "connecting" and never changes. I am using the atest version of chrome. What coud be causing it?

The signaling server is checkd to be working alright.

```
var ottowa = initIO({//Init a connection to the signaling server
    onMessage: function(data) { //got message from the signalin server
        trace("onMessage with data = " + JSON.stringify(data));

        //var signal = JSON.parse(data.toString());
        var signal = data;

        if(signal.title == "offer")
            gotOffer(signal.data);
        else if (signal.title == "offerResponse")
            gotResponse(signal.data);

    },
    onCount: function(data) {

    }
});

var configuration = {
    'iceServers': [{
        'url':'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
    }]
};

joinRoom('demo');//Joins a room in the signaloing server

var pc, channel;

pc = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(configuration, { 'optional': [{'DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement': true}, {'RtpDataChannels': true }] }); 
channel = pc.createDataChannel("data");

pc.onaddstream = function(obj){
    trace("onaddstream");
}

function initCall(){
    pc.createOffer(function(offer) {
        pc.setLocalDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer), function() {
            send({//send a message thru the signaling server
                title: "offer",
                data: offer
            });
        }, error);
    },error);
}

function gotOffer(offer) {
    pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer), function() {
        pc.createAnswer(function(answer) {
            pc.setLocalDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(answer), function(){
                send({//send a message thru the signaling server
                    title:"offerResponse",
                    data: answer
                });
            }, error);
        },error);
    },error);
}

function gotResponse(offer) {
    pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer), function() {
        trace("gotResponse and successfully connected");
    },error);
}

channel.onopen = function(event) {
    trace("onopen with event = " + event);
}

channel.onmessage = function(event) {
    trace("onmessage with event = " + event);
}

function trace(text) {
    console.log((performance.now() / 1000).toFixed(3) + ": " + text.toString);
}

function error(err) {
    trace("error = " + err);
}
```

Comment: as of a few months ago, data channels weren't fully implemented...

Comment: I believe you'll find you answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470291/rtcdatachannels-readystate-is-not-open/

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any firewall or other network device that might block the connection? Connecting to signalling servers generally works as that is an outgoing connection (client to server), but RTC goes client to client, outgoing and incoming. Most firewalls block that, so you might check that first.