# Failed to execute 'send' on 'RTCDataChannel': RTCDataChannel.readyState is not 'open'

Tags: javascript, web, webrtc, simplewebrtc

I am trying to learn WebRTC . I copied some codes and i get this error:

Failed to execute 'send' on 'RTCDataChannel': RTCDataChannel.readyState is not 'open'

Any one can help?

code score: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/webrtc_text_demo.htm

Comment: How are you running your application???

Comment: Have you installed all required libraries for your app through `npm install` ??

Comment: I believe this should help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470291/rtcdatachannels-readystate-is-not-open

Comment: Also take a look over the MDN too : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCDataChannel/readyState

Comment: Share your full code...That's the Tutorial link..!

Comment: I run the server with node (cmd) and the html file in the browers.
I did install via npm.
I looked at these links and i cound find any help there.

Comment: my code is exectly the code from the totorial. i just copied it

Comment: i have tried anothr totorial at :
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/webrtc_sending_messages.htm
i have the same problem. what am i missing ?

Comment: Those tutorials are old! Try removing `{optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]}`. That old Chrome-only stuff no longer works.

Comment: Well I cant see the original error any more but the program still wont function correctly. The message was not transferred .  What is wrong ? 
Maybe its connected to another error i get  " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token H in JSON at position 0 " ?

Comment: after removing this line it seems to send the data but on the other side of the datachanle the onmmesege even wont triger

Answer (score 12):

Add `ondatachannel` handling after removing `{optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]}`:

```
  myConnection.onicecandidate = function (event) { 

     if (event.candidate) { 
        send({ 
           type: "candidate", 
           candidate: event.candidate 
        });
     } 
  }; 

  myConnection.ondatachannel = function(event) {
     var receiveChannel = event.channel;
     receiveChannel.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log("ondatachannel message:", event.data);
     };
  };

  openDataChannel();
```

Comment: This should be the answer! Tried this and worked perfectly after trying for hours! Why is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

The same error was thrown to me .This is because your peers are not connected and you are sending data.This was solved by this:

```
peer.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('I am connected now')
    peer.send('sending data blah blah')
  })
```